# How to get "İ" instead of "I" when using the upper filter on "i" in Twig

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, twig

In Turkish, `i` must be written as `İ` when in uppercase.

The `upper` filter in Twig ouputs `I`. Is there a workaround ?

My website, built on Symfony 2, has several languages, so this must only be set for the Turkish version.

Here is the Twig :

```
<h2 class="h1">{{ 'des.iwid.resourcecentre.title'|trans|upper }}</h2>
```

And my `des.iwid.resourcecentre.title` tag is "`Bilgi Merkezi`"

The output is "`BILGI MERKEZI`" instead of "`BİLGI MERKEZİ`"

Thanks !

Comment: can you post what you had tried so far?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I've edited my question.

Comment: Thanks @COil but I'm looking for uppercase, not capitalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, my workaround for now is not to use the `|upper`filter, but using the `text-transform :uppercase;` CSS property which works nicely on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

And use this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php

Comment: Isn't it juste the same as the upper filter ?

Comment: Slight problem there:Unicode [maps i to I](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0069/index.htm). The conversion function would ideally look at the locale settings, but `mb-strtoupper` explicitly does not do that.

Comment: Yes, I've just red something about this. the "İ" character exists in Unicode, but there is a need to take into account the locale to have the "correct" conversion.